# Помогите подобрать gateway для gRPC мкросервисов

Tags: микросервисы, kubernetes, grpc

У меня есть кластер K8s с Linkerd. В нем запущено несколько микросервисов, принимающих запросы по gRPC. Моя задача создать единый gateway, принимающий все запросы от клиентов в нескольких форматах(об этом далее) и распределяющих их между соответствующими сервисами.
Я нашел несколько распространенных решений вроде Envoy, но все они рассчитаны на принятие запросов в REST и перекодировании в gRPC для последующей переправки сервисам. Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем случае некоторые клиенты используют сразу gRPC для подключения к серверу, по этому мне требуется аналог работающий с gRPC не только на выходе но и на входе. Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого мне нужен gateway прокси соответствующий следующим пунктам:
1) он должен принимать все входящие запросы по gRPC (и желательно REST)
2) затем перенаправлять эти запросы соответствующим сервисам, при необходимости произведя перекодирование в gRPC
Балансирование и сбор статистики не требуются, т.к. в моем кластере работает Linked, берущий на себя этот функционал.
Прошу помочь с подбором подходящего под мои цели прокси гейтвея.

P.S. Если не существует решений слушающих и gRPC и REST в одном месте, подскажите решения только для grpc и на входе и на выходе, т.к. rest->grpc решений навалом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Nginx-ingress может помочь с этим вопросом:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/grpc

Соответсвенно нужно будет создать несколько ingress правил: для gRPC и для http.